# File Connection Error in R(ML hacker, trying to build email classifier)

Tags: r, machine-learning, connection, analytics, analysis

I am new to R and I am practicing how to build email classifier (ML for Hacker). I got stuck in a error. The code is:

```
spam.path <- file.path("./spam/")
spam.docs <- dir(spam.path)
spam.docs <- spam.docs[which(spam.docs!="cmds")]
get.msg <- function(path) {
    con <- file(path, open="rt", encoding="latin1")
    text <- readLines(con)
    msg <- text[seq(which(text=="")[1]+1,length(text),1)]
    close(con)
    return(paste(msg, collapse="\n"))
}

all.spam <-  sapply(spam.docs, function(p) get.msg(paste(spam.path,p,sep="")))
```

and the error is:

```
Error in file(path, open = "rt", encoding = "latin1") : 
cannot open the connection 

In addition: Warning message:
In file(path, open = "rt", encoding = "latin1") :
cannot open file './spam00001.7848dde101aa985090474a91ec93fcf0': No such file or directory.`
```

I set the directory correctly and verify through this command - `list.files(spam)`
and it is displaying all the files completely. I searched the whole web and couldn't find the solution. I don't know what I did wrong.

Comment: Try using `dir(... , full.names = T)`

Comment: I tried but it is not working, giving the same error. @tobiasegil_te

Comment: I can't reproduce your error, for me it works as it should (I copied your code 1:1). However, your error message suggests a missing "/" in the path. Are you sure that you have used exactly this code?

Comment: BTW: your question has nothing to do with machine learning (even though you're working on a ML project). You should only use tags that are directly related to your question.

Comment: I will keep in mind from next time (about tags).